# What to do about a dental infection?

Tags: dentistry, infection, antibiotics

I have an infection in my gums, similar to the picture below. The 'pimple' has gotten bigger and than shrank back down but never disappeared.Mine being only one and much smaller. Besides taking antibiotic medication, is there any other treatment? I heard gargling with salt water every morning helps but not sure about it

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Good afternoon,

**I'll methodically address each part of your question. The important elements are in bold**

The abscesses in your mouth won't heal on their own, if the underlying  cause is not removed. **It will most likely reappear after you stop taking the antibiotics, which should not be used in a long term fashion.**

If these are dental abscesses, There are generally two possible causes:

*Peri-apical Abscesses:* The pulp (nerf) inside the tooth has died (necrotic) and the bacteria have reached the apex (bottom of the tooth).

Generally a **root canal** is sufficient to prevent entry of further bacteria and enable the body to repair the bone and allow the abscess to heal.
Another possibility is to extract the tooth, if it is not possible to perform a root canal or to restore it afterward (with a crown for example).

*Periodontal Abscesses:*
The gums around the tooth have detached from the roots, allowing bacteria to thrive in so-called periodontal pockets between supporting tissues and the rooth of the tooth.
Depending on the state of the tooth, if it is salvageable, it will require **scaling and root planing** to clean the area of bacterial debris and to allow the gums to reattach to the root. **Using saltwater can help control the bacteria, but will not get ride of the pockets which let bacteria accumulate in the first place.** 
Another possibility is again to extract the tooth, if there is not sufficient bone and gums to support the tooth

**As always, only an exam by a dental professional will allow you to find and treat the cause of your abscess(es).**

*Sources*:

- My professional background
- previous question on Health.Stackexchange
- https://www.coeurdaleneiddentist.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-periapical-and-periodontal-abscess/